# How do you generate more than one Google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have been trying to get two(need three) Google maps to work on my project.

I have got the first one working with this;

```
<div class="map" id="map"></div>



function initMap() {
var uluru = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: uluru
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: uluru,
  map: map
});
}
```

Now when I try to get a second one working it just doesn't work. I have tried to find other solutions but to no luck.

These two other maps are on a different page than this one above.

From looking at some stuff could it be as simple as below? I have tried things similar to this with no luck as well.

```
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
<div class="map" id="map__2"></div>

function initMap() {
var uluru = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
var uluru_SecondMap = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: uluru
});
var map_SecondMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map__2'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: uluru
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: uluru,
  map: map
});
var marker_SecondMap = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: uluru,
  map: map
});
}
```

I think I might be making this way harder than it needs to be, but I have found it strange that Google themselves don't have an example(they might do I just haven't seen it) for this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have  proper width and heigth for the two div

and be sure you have an event for trigger the initMap() exacuption

and be sure that the two maps use the related  map object  map and map_SecondMap

```
  <div class="map" id="map"  style='height: 300px; width:300px'></div>
  <div class="map" id="map2" style='height: 300px; width:300px'></div>

  function initMap() {
      var uluru = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
      var uluru_SecondMap = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
      });
      var map_SecondMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru_SecondMap
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
      });
      var marker_SecondMap = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru_SecondMap,
        map: map_SecondMap
      });
  }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Comment: Both of these work but I saw this one first and it helped me realise what I was doing wrong, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong. I was able to use your code almost as is to get two maps on the same page. Two things I changed:

1. I made sure both `divs` had dimensions
2. I changed you second marker to be applied to `map_SecondMap`

Here's the entire HTML that works,just in case you see something that's different than yours:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .map{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
    <div class="map" id="map__2"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
            var uluru_SecondMap = {lat: 54.5973, lng: -5.9301};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: uluru
            });
            var map_SecondMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map__2'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
            });
            var marker_SecondMap = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map_SecondMap
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You and me both. I think it was just one of those ones where I just got my wire mixed up. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: I just realised that the way this is done means that each 'map' needs to be getting called on one page. I was using this to call maps over two pages with one of them missing so this broke it. This is what I was doing wrong before, thought I would just let you know what I was doing wrong.